# Duplicate code removal: nesting cases

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

So, I am working on a structure-conversion class that is supposed to move files in our system from one situation to another.

As it sits, I have a number of `List<File>` containing the xml items that need to be moved separated by prefix (because each has slightly differing rules). The data for the new location comes from the files themselves.

I now run into the issue that much of my logic stays the same: Basically, I loop over the list, do some generic logic to determine the location it has to go to, do some specific logic, then I do generic actions followed by specific actions.

```
for(...){
    if(GENERIC_LOGIC){
        if(SPECIFIC_LOGIC){
            doGenericAction();
            doSpecificAction();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the actual code isn't nearly as clean. Every one of these bits is a block of around 4 lines.

Now, my question relates to condensing the generic logic clauses into a manageable form. I've never had to refactor encasing statements before, just inner statements. Can someone give me some pointers on doing this cleanly and with the smallest amount of code grime? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the re-formatting Berger. I couldn't get it right and was already running late for a meeting!

Answer (score 0):

*Probably* the cleanest solution would be to use an abstract class, which defines the generic logic and then create other classes which define the specific logic.

When you are iterating over the files, you would then create an instance of the appropriate handler class and let it do the rest.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'm not a huge fan of single-method classes though. Food for thought!

Comment: @WeckarE.: Keep in mind that this way, you would be able to make amendements to one behaviour without potentially breaking the rest. It is true, you might have a number of small classes, but this way, you will have a design which is more flexible (at least in my opinion).